# Facebook LIke Button comes Twice in my Web page

Tags: html, facebook-like

I have a facebook Like button in my website.
[image]

I have kept the Like Button only once.
When I try it in my local system. I get the Like button  correctly But the same index.html when put Live shows me 2 like button .. How do I handle this .

[image: In Local only one Like button is there]

Comment: Hard to help without any code... did you tried inspecting both elements with your browser? If you share a link, that would help too.

Comment: you may also wish to hide the fact that your username is `123`. Just saying

Comment: Site is [http://www.bimmtechnologies.com/](http://www.bimmtechnologies.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, from looking at the source the problem is:

```
<div id="callUs" style="FLOAT: right"><a>Call us: +91-95661 60513<br ><span>email: bimmtechnologies@gmail.com</span></a></div>
<div align="right" class="fb-like" data-href="http://bimmtechnologies.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.bimmtechnologies.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; width:200px; height:40px">
</iframe>
```

there seems to be only one iFrame, yet inspecting DOM gives you:

```
<div id="callUs" style="float: right;"><a>Call us: +91-95661 60513<br><span>email: bimmtechnologies@gmail.com</span></a></div>
<div class="fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" data-href="http://bimmtechnologies.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" align="right">
    <span style="height: 29px; width: 450px;">
        <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D5%23cb%3Df1d310dc178f298%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.bimmtechnologies.com%252Ffd67aabbddb5%26domain%3Dwww.bimmtechnologies.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;extended_social_context=false&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fbimmtechnologies.com%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=en_US&amp;node_type=link&amp;sdk=joey&amp;send=true&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450" class="fb_ltr " title="Like this content on Facebook." style="border: medium none; overflow: hidden; height: 29px; width: 450px;" name="f2e9ee7de90f1f6" id="f7f40995b577b2" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </span>
</div>
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.bimmtechnologies.com/" style="border: medium none; width: 200px; height: 40px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Some strange java-script is adding content into the div with class "fb-like":

```
<div align="right" class="fb-like" data-href="http://bimmtechnologies.com/" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
</div>
```

If you disable javascript, notice how the double disappears.

### Fix

remove the aforementioned `div` as well as:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

which appears right after

```
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your code because you really have two iframes generating fb buttons. You have one div with class .fb-like fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget (the one that is styled, which makes me think is the right one), and right after you close this div you have another iframe tag that you can try to delete. As a last option, try this in your style.css file: #header > iframe { display: none; } - Hope it helps!

Comment: Yep, but the fb button is being dynamically generated. I do believe you don't need that <iframe> tag that's right after the 'empty' div.